# После нахождения пользователя в mongo с помощью mongoose, хочу удалить поле , но оно остается

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

delete возвращает true, но console.log в строчке ниже и на frontend все равно имеет поле password

```js
router.post("/get-cart/", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { userId } = req.user;
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
        const userData = await user.populate('cart.items.productId').execPopulate()
        console.log(delete userData.password)
        console.log(userData)
        res.json(userData)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).json({message: "internal server error"})
    }
})
```

Comment: А для чего вам нужно удалять поле `password`?

Comment: Я не хочу, чтобы на frontend пришел пароль, только email, данные из корзины и email

Comment: А если так `userData.password = undefined`?

Comment: Так, конечно, работает,но я хочу понять, почему с  delete не работает, код один в один при авторизации работает норм и не хочется, чтобы на frontend было лишнее поле с пустым значением

Comment: Когда гуглил про `delete`, то говорилось, что оно может не сработать если в `prototype` есть удаляемое поле